# ArcGIS rest API error The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api

I'm using the rest API to add a feature to a public feature layer and it's giving me the error "Error: 1000, Description: The given key was not present in the dictionary". What does this mean? How do I fix?

My feature service: http://services2.arcgis.com/lfD49qylDsb6IIcE/arcgis/rest/services/PropertiesWordpressLoading/FeatureServer/0

I add my feature using this form: /services/PropertiesWordpressLoading/FeatureServer/0/applyEdits

My json:
[
  {
    "geometry" : {"x" : -86.288146369965, "y" : 32.842269287433}, 
    "attributes" : {
      "CATEGORY" : 'For Sale',
      "LIST_ID" : '00-000',
      "CMN_NAME" : 'Toly Test Tract'
    }
  }
]

I get the same result if I use the form located in http://services2.arcgis.com/lfD49qylDsb6IIcE/arcgis/rest/services/PropertiesWordpressLoading/FeatureServer/0/addFeatures

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is an esri bug having something to do with time-aware layers. When I turned off time awareness, everything worked.